# Как сделать отправку писем-напоминаний сотрудникам о ДР в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, xmpp

В документации Битрикс не сказано, как установить синхронизацию дня рождения сотрудников с календарём. Задача в том, чтобы руководителю отправлялось на почту письмо-напоминание о Дне Рождении сотрудника. Как это сделать?

Comment: 1. Сделать синхронизацию с календарем 2. Написать скрипт напоминалки

Comment: Пример можете представить? Хотя бы что-то.

Comment: А с каким календарем должна быть синхронизация?

Comment: Внутренний, Битрикс-календарь

Comment: Попросить сотрудников внести информацию о дате рождения в профиль не судьба? Поле же есть.

Comment: они внесут. как (после чего) их руководитель увидит дни рождения у себя в календаре?

Comment: Календарь Битрикса если не ошибаюсь подтягивает данные о днях рождения в себя. Также дни рождения текущего месяца отображаются в правой панельке.

Comment: Текущего месяца, да. Календарь не подтягивает данные о др. В календаре создается событие, как его далее привязать, чтобы оно всплывало у человека.